# Proper Response Status when query parameters do not match

Tags: html, rest

I am building a REST API, and my GET functions modify the data according to some query parameters.

BUT!, when I get a query parameter combination that I do not support I would like to return the correct Response Code.

Can anyone please help me understand what response code I should use in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

The proper HTTP Status code to return would be a simple:

400 - Bad Request

followed by a reason for why the request failed.  This informs the client that the issue was with how they requested the information, in your case, an illegal query parameter combination.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends also on what you are striving after. You could ignore this and not act at all, but like @AniAko mentioned you could also throw a 400 error with a descriptive error message (for example which fields are allowed or what field or value in the request was invalid).

For choosing the "correct" solution there are several things to consider:

- **Security**

  Maybe you will give away useful information to people trying to exploit your web application (See [this post on security.stackexchange.com](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/209014/how-strict-should-i-be-in-rejecting-unexpected-query-parameters) on similar topic).
- **Usability**

  If you are building a rest API that will also be consumed by other parties it would be useful for the users of your API to be notified about invalid request parameters (from a developer point of view).
- **Performance and maintenance**

  Maybe validating the parameters will create overhead that you would rather skip to make a performant API or maybe you don't have the resources to write and maintain the code that is needed to do this validation.

In other words: I don't think this is only about ***best-practice*** but also about ***most-suitable***.